# Single value in where clause

Tags: rdf, sparql, ontology, owlim, graphdb

Hi I have a SPARQL query that has has this in the where clause

```
...
optional {
        ?v foo:thing ?something .
        $dontgetthis
        ?v bar:somethingelse ?otherthing .
...
}
...
```

Now, I get most of this, except one thing.  I don't get `$dontgetthis`.  What does this mean?  `$dontgetthis` is not used anywhere else in the query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dollar sign is a legal variable prefix in SPARQL, so you can use variables like `$v`, but that doesn't appear to be what's happening.  You can have an optional as the only thing within a WHERE, so a query like this is legal:

```sql
prefix foo: <>
prefix bar: <>
select * where { 
  optional {
          ?v foo:thing ?something .
          ?v bar:somethingelse ?otherthing .
  }
}
```

I'd rather wonder whether the query you're seeing with`$dontgetthis` inside is a string where `$dontgetthis` is going to be replaced by something else by some other code.  It's not legal SPARQL by itself.

Comment: Does that mean that a variable can be prefixed with either a dollar or a question mark?  Is there any difference between these two?

Comment: The only difference is that one begins with a question mark, and the other begins with a dollar sign.  `$foo` and `?foo` are the same variable.  The (freely available online, so this isn't secret information or anything) spec *explicitly* says so:  *"**[4.1.3 Syntax for Query Variables](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#QSynVariables)** A query variable is marked by the use of either "?" or "$"; the "?" or "$" is not part of the variable name. In a query, $abc and ?abc identify the same variable."*

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor But isn't `$` customarily used for query params, i.e. vars that will be bound from the outside when the query is executed?

Comment: @VladimirAlexiev Some people might have that convention.  I've never seen it before, though.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Yeah, the sesame (rdf4j) people: http://docs.rdf4j.org/rest-api/#_repository_queries and search for `$<varname>`